# Drawing an isosceles triangle/arrow with two points

Tags: java, geometry, trigonometry

I have been trying to figure this one out for some time now, I am making a program that uses a triangle as an arrow and been trying to figure out how to make an arrow with two points, meaning that that the first point would be at the midpoint of the base of the triangle, while the second point would be at the tip facing the direction away from the first point.

This crude paint drawing should help figure out what I am talking about
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3ktz.png (Would put direct images but don't have enough rep)

Now, I went through and tried figuring out how to calculate those other two endpoints of the triangle so I could make the polygon, but I am not doing it correctly because I am getting a triangle that isn't isosceles and the endpoints don't create a line perpendicular to the original line.

What I am currently getting (With some drawing over it to show the points)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dljsn.png

My current code

```
public class Triangle extends Shape{

private boolean assigned = false;

private int[] x;

private int[] y;

public Triangle(Point startPoint, Point endPoint){
    this.startPoint = startPoint;
    this.endPoint = endPoint;
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    if(!assigned) {
        x = new int[3];
        y = new int[3];
        double distance = startPoint.distance(endPoint);
        double halfDistance = distance/2;
        double angle = getAngle(startPoint,endPoint)- Math.PI/2.0;

        x[0] = (int)endPoint.getX();
        y[0] = (int)endPoint.getY();

        x[1] = (int)((Math.sin(angle)*halfDistance) + startPoint.getX());
        y[1] = (int)((Math.cos(angle)*halfDistance) + startPoint.getY());

        x[2] = (int)(startPoint.getX() - (Math.sin(angle)*halfDistance));
        y[2] = (int)(startPoint.getY() - (Math.cos(angle)*halfDistance));


        assigned = true;
        if(endPoint.distance(x[1],y[1]) == (Math.sqrt(5)*halfDistance))
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Confirm Correct 1");
        if(endPoint.distance(x[1],y[1]) == endPoint.distance(x[2],y[2]))
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Confirm Correct 2");
    }
    g.fillPolygon(x,y,3);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
}

private double getAngle(Point pointOne, Point pointTwo){
    double angle = Math.atan2(pointTwo.getY()- pointOne.getY(),pointTwo.getX()-pointOne.getX());
    while(angle < 0){
        angle += (2.0*Math.PI);
    }
    return angle;
}
```

}

I have working at this for hours and can't seem to figure it out, someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up replacing `double angle = getAngle(startPoint,endPoint)- Math.PI/2.0;` with something more like `double angle = -Math.atan2(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x);`

I wrote this little test program, which allows you to move to points around a circle and which generates the resulting triangle...

[image: Tri]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane tp = new TestPane();
                JPanel control = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                control.add(tp);

                final JSlider startAngel = new JSlider(0, 359);
                final JSlider endAngel = new JSlider(0, 359);

                JPanel sliders = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
                sliders.add(startAngel);
                sliders.add(endAngel);

                startAngel.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        tp.setStartAngle(startAngel.getValue());
                    }
                });
                endAngel.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        tp.setEndAngle(endAngel.getValue());
                    }
                });

                startAngel.setValue(0);
                endAngel.setValue(180);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(control);
                frame.add(sliders, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Point startPoint, endPoint;
        private float startAngle = 0;
        private float endAngle = 180;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            super.invalidate();
            recalculate();
        }

        protected void recalculate() {

            int dim = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
            dim -= 50;
            float radius = dim / 2f;

            startPoint = getPointOnCircle(startAngle, radius);
            endPoint = getPointOnCircle(endAngle, radius);

            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected Point getPointOnCircle(float degress, float radius) {

            int x = Math.round(getWidth() / 2);
            int y = Math.round(getHeight() / 2);

            double rads = Math.toRadians(degress - 90); // 0 becomes the top

            // Calculate the outter point of the line
            int xPosy = Math.round((float) (x + Math.cos(rads) * radius));
            int yPosy = Math.round((float) (y + Math.sin(rads) * radius));

            return new Point(xPosy, yPosy);

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int[] x = new int[3];
            int[] y = new int[3];
            double distance = startPoint.distance(endPoint);
            double halfDistance = distance / 2;
            double angle = -Math.atan2(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x);

            System.out.println(angle);

            x[0] = (int) endPoint.getX();
            y[0] = (int) endPoint.getY();

            x[1] = (int) ((Math.sin(angle) * halfDistance) + startPoint.getX());
            y[1] = (int) ((Math.cos(angle) * halfDistance) + startPoint.getY());

            x[2] = (int) (startPoint.getX() - (Math.sin(angle) * halfDistance));
            y[2] = (int) (startPoint.getY() - (Math.cos(angle) * halfDistance));

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillPolygon(x, y, 3);

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.fillOval(startPoint.x - 5, startPoint.y - 5, 10, 10);
            g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g2d.fillOval(endPoint.x - 5, endPoint.y - 5, 10, 10);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void setStartAngle(float value) {
            startAngle = value;
            recalculate();
        }

        public void setEndAngle(float value) {
            endAngle = value;
            recalculate();
        }

    }

}
```

If that still gives you some weird results, apart from sharing some test data, I might consider using something like `Math.atan2(Math.abs(endPoint.y - startPoint.y), Math.abs(endPoint.x - startPoint.x))` or simular

Comment: Almost, I had gotten that at some point also, but it only works with nice angles, putting in a "weird" angle produces this http://i.imgur.com/HILpcgr.png

Comment: Well, stop putting in weird angles :P

Comment: Lol, k. Or if you angle down (negative degrees btwn angles) it makes some awkward triangles

Comment: Oh ok, it works just fine if the startPoint.y is greater than the endPoint.y hmmmmm

Comment: Okay, wrote a test program which allows you to move the two points about a central radius point to test it...see updates...

Comment: Tested it with the program that I have. The "double angle = -Math.atan2(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x);" Worked PERFECTLY, thank you, I spent, I don't know how many, hours on this, I knew it was just some simple error I was making lol. (I am guessing I was being thrown off by the coord-plane starting at topleft corner or something like that). Thanks again so much. I would upvote you, but too low of rep lol.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate angles at all.

```
    double startX = 40;
    double startY = 120;
    double endX = 110;
    double endY = 15;

    double deltaX =  ( startY - endY ) / 2;
    double deltaY =  ( endX - startX ) / 2;

    double[] polygonX = new double[3];
    double[] polygonY = new double[3];

    polygonX[0] = endX;
    polygonY[0] = endY;

    polygonX[1] = startX - deltaX;
    polygonY[1] = startY - deltaY;

    polygonX[2] = startX + deltaX;
    polygonY[2] = startY + deltaY;
```

[image: Same angle]

The drawing is VERY bad :D, but the point is that:

`cos(ang) = 'distance' / ( startY - endY )`
and
`cod(ang) = ('distance'/2) / deltaX`
so
`deltaX = ( startY - endY ) / 2`

The same aplies to `deltaY =  ( endX - startX ) / 2`

So the other 2 point of the triangle, will be the startPoint minus and plus those deltas.

Comment: This is incorrect, I had to think about it for a bit, but using this method works much like my original error, it keeps the distance from the startPoint the same, but does not guarantee that you will get the points perpendicular to the original "path", even with your own numbers I got this http://i.imgur.com/QQTMCDh.png, which isn't what I am looking for.   Yours would only work in the case of a 45 degree angles (and its counterparts, 45 degrees + 90*n degrees). Thanks anyways though, made me try to rethink without angles :D

Comment: sorry.. there was a bug in the code, you should deltaX on start X and vice-versa. I edited it, try it now ;)

Comment: Oh, ok, I see  now. Yea, a lot of it didn't make sense in the original but yea, this works just as well (Probably a little faster because it doesn't have to do angle calculations). Thanks!

Comment: Oh yea, definitely faster, each time to calculate using the delta method takes a couple hundred nanoseconds, while using the angle method takes a couple thousand nanoseconds. Thanks for making me look bad lol.